# Change the scope of a remote origin in git

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I recently started to use git/github.  What drove me to it was an online course, and now I am looking to do things on my own.

As I want to look at the code for an R package, the caret package, I forked it in my github account.  Then I created a folder to clone it into and added the origin.

The error that I get is `remote origin already exists`. When I check the remote origins with `git remote -v`, I get a github address from a previous project from my online course.

My question about the scope (folderwise) of the origins is because the online course project location is very far away from the caret folder that I created.

How can I modify the origins in order to clone that project?  I will also appreciate a brief explanation on how these repos are handled by git.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git remote set-url`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote set-url origin /new/url
```

That will replace the url associated with the remote '`origin`' with a new one.

Comment: Would you know why it was assuming an origin from a repo that is stored in a folder far far away?

Comment: When you clone into your folder, git automatically set the origin to the path of the repo you are cloning.